# React.js: how to sort() and map() or only map() conditionally in JSX

Tags: reactjs, sorting, conditional-statements, mapping

I have this code below which doesn't seem to be effective as I use almost the same code twice. I would like to make this code much cleaner than this by not just pasting and copying.

```js
<div >
{ selected ? (
  dynamicData
    .sort((a, b) => b.count_filtered - a.count_filtered) // Only this part is different
    .map((list, idx) => (
      <div key={list.slug}>
        <label htmlFor={list.slug}>
          {list.name} (<b> {list.count_filtered} </b> / {list.count_all})
        </label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          value={list.slug}
          id={list.slug}
          checked={filterList.some(el => el.slug.includes(list.slug))}
        />
      </div>
    ))
) : (
  dynamicData.map((list, idx) => (
    <div key={list.slug}>
      <label htmlFor={list.slug}>
        {list.name} (<b> {list.count_filtered} </b> / {list.count_all})
      </label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        value={list.slug}
        id={list.slug}
        checked={filterList.some(el => el.slug.includes(list.slug))}
      />
    </div>
  ))
)}
</div>
```

As you can see, if `selected` is `true`, the array is going to `sort()` and `map()` otherwise, it will only do `map()`.

Please let me know the clever way to clean this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const repeatCode = (
    <div key={list.slug}>
      <label htmlFor={list.slug}>
        {list.name} (<b> {list.count_filtered} </b> / {list.count_all})
      </label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        value={list.slug}
        id={list.slug}
        checked={filterList.some(el => el.slug.includes(list.slug))}
      />
    </div>
)
```

```
<div >
{ selected ? (
  dynamicData
    .sort((a, b) => b.count_filtered - a.count_filtered) // Only this part is different
    .map((list, idx) => (
      {repeatCode}
    ))
) : (
  dynamicData.map((list, idx) => (
      {repeatCode}
  ))
)}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I actually needed to apply your code a bit differently as there is `list` when mapping, but yeah, this logic works fine for me! Thank you again :)

Comment: Can u show how u added the list part? I would like to know and will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Now go check what I just updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to what `@MuhammedJaseem` said, I updated my code below, and it works well.

```js
const repeatCode = (list, onChange) => { // Added
  return (
    <div key={list.slug}>
      <label htmlFor={list.slug}>
        {list.name} (<b> {list.count_filtered} </b> / {list.count_all})
      </label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        value={list.slug}
        id={list.slug}
        checked={filterList.some(el => el.slug.includes(list.slug))}
        onChange={e => onChange(e.target.checked, list.slug, dynamicType)} // Added
      />
    </div>
)}
```

```js
<div >
{ selected ? (
  dynamicData
    .sort((a, b) => b.count_filtered - a.count_filtered) 
    .map((list, idx) => (
      repeatCode(list, handleSelect)
    ))
) : (
  dynamicData.map((list, idx) => (
      repeatCode(list, handleSelect)
  ))
)}
</div>
```